# migrating function to typescript from JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am implementing a working JS function to typescript, but I'm getting an error on parameters: "error, success"

> [tslint] Parentheses are required around the parameters of an arrow function definition (arrow-parens)

```
function chapa() {
  console.log('altered');
  TouchID.isSupported()
  .then(authenticate)
  .catch(error => {
    AlertIOS.alert('TouchID not supported');
  });
}
```

so the "error" is underlined with error, with this message:

> [tslint] Parentheses are required around the parameters of an arrow function definition (arrow-parens)

how should I pass then the "error" parameter?, cheers

Comment: So add () around the parameters like it says.... If you do not understand the error messages, look them up, they typically have solutions. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as it says, put parentheses around the parameter:

`.catch((error: any) => {`

Comment: hi , thanks, but it also needed the type, so (error : any)

Answer (score 4):

If you'd rather not add parentheses around the parameter (it's not strictly required by Typescript), add the following to the `rules` object in your tslint.json file.

```
"arrow-parens": [true, "ban-single-arg-parens"]
```

Check out https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/ and https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/arrow-parens/ for more details.